# Htaccess rewrite subfolder to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain, subdirectory

i have a domain with many subdomain; what i want to do is to map specific subdomains do specific subfolder.

let's suppose the domain is `example.com`, i have these domains:

- example.com
- www.example.com
- demo1.example.com
- demo2.example.com

and 2 subfolders in my `var/www/html` folder:

- /var/www/html (for `example.com` and `www.example.com`)
- /var/www/html/demo1 (for `demo1.example.com`)
- /var/www/html/demo2 (for `demo2.example.com`)

So what i want to is set up the correct mapping so that:

- opening `(www.)example.com/demo1` should redirect to `demo1.example.com`
- opening `(www.)example.com/demo2` should redirect to `demo2.example.com`
- opening `(www.)example.com/anything-else` should do nothing (content in /var/www/html)

Obviusly `demo1.example.com` should use the content in `/var/www/html/demo1` and `demo2.example.com` should use the content in `/var/www/html/demo2`

Comment: Do you have access to Apache .conf files?

Comment: Yes, full access but i preferr to do just with htaccess

Comment: You certainly should prefer to use the real configuration for various reasons. Dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") are only offered as a last options if nothing else is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to implement rules handling both directions: 
1. redireting requests to the "www" host to the "subdomain" (actually another host name) 
2. rewriting requests to the non-www hosts to a folder, if such folder exists

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?demo1/(.*)$ https://demo1.example.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?demo2/(.*)$ https://demo2.example.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo1\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /demo1/%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo2\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /demo2/%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA]
```

You could certainly implement a more generalized rule for the second part (the internal rewriting), but above explicit approach is easier to reach, thus easier to maintain. I prefer it for that reason.

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

These rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks, although it works, i ended up configuring differents virtual hosts (one for each subdomain) and not using anymore the htaccess.

Comment: Certainly possible for a small, fixed set of host names (those are host names, _not_ "domains" or "sub domains"). If you have control over the server configuration however, then why didn't you simply go with a single host and place those rules in its configuration? Just as I suggested?

Comment: What do you mean? i have a vps that i'm using for some test, and actually it hosts different websites. I now setted up many "sites" of apache, do you think there's a bettere solution? (the websites aren't related one with each other)

Comment: I explicitly mentioned that you can implement rewriting rules in the http server's host configuration.